# Horn formulas, existential second order logic and the Cardinality constraint

Tags: complexity-theory, descriptive-complexity, finite-model-theory

Consider this Problem $P$ as follows: $~$ Given a set $S$ and a constant $K$.. $~$Is there a subset $M$ of $S$, such that $|M| \ge K$?

Of course, $P$ can be easily solved in time polynomial in $|S|$.. $~$We can design a Turing machine $T$ which decides YES or NO in polynomial time... Of course, $M$ is **not** given -- it is an unknown to be determined -- it is a quantified relation, a second order predicate ($\exists M$).

On the one hand, we can argue that $P$ cannot be expressed as a Horn formula.. Consider an instance of $P$.. $~$Let $S = \{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h\}$ and $K = 5$.. $~$Consider 2 solution sets $M_1$ and $M_2$ to the given instance of $P$ as follows: $~M_1 = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ and $M_2 = \{d, e, f, g, h\}$..

Or, for $M_1$, we can write $~M_1(a) = M_1(b) = M_1(c) = M_1(d) = M_1(e) = TRUE~$ and $~M_1(f) = M_1(g) = M_1(h) = FALSE$... Similarly for $M_2$.

$~|M_1| \ge 5$ and $|M_2| \ge 5$, so both $M_1$ and $M_2$ are feasible solutions to our instance of $P$.. $~$But $|M_1 \cap M_2| = |\{d, e\}| = 2 < 5$.. $~$We know that Horn solution sets are closed under intersection (that is, if 2 solution sets are feasible, then their intersection is also feasible).. $~$But in our case, we have an intersection set ($M_1 \cap M_2$) which is **not** a feasible solution to this instance of $P$.

From this and since $M$ is a second order relation, we conclude that $P$ **cannot** be expressed as an ESO Horn formula.

On the other hand, since $P$ can be solved in polynomial time, from [[1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0020821)], Corollary 7.10 of
[[2](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-0539-5_8)] and Theorem 8.4 of [[3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201530821)], we
know that $P$ can be expressed in ESO universal Horn (existential second order logic where
the first order part is a universal Horn formula) with successor
relations..  $~$The computation of the Turing machine $T$ (mentioned above) can be encoded in this logic.

(I guess the "$\exists M$" will appear in the expression of $T$'s computation in a different form.)

But this contradicts our earlier conclusion that $P$ *cannot* be expressed as an ESO Horn formula! $~$

I'm confused.. $~$Why the contradictory results?

(PS: $~$Of course, the question in Problem $P$ can be answered by simply checking whether $|S| \ge K$.. But for the purposes of theoretical clarification, let us stick with $P$ as described above.)

Comment: I don't see any relation between being not able to express a certain property in the horn logic and the ability to describe runs of Turing machines in a stronger logic. Well FO cannot express that your domain is even, but with a built-in order and existentially quantified predicates you can do it. So were is the contradiction?

Comment: Actually since $M$ is a second order relation, we can say that $P$ cannot be expressed as an ESO-Horn formula. (I have edited the question.)

Comment: But you don't want to express P as a relation (whatever you mean by it), but a Turing machine solving such a problem...

Comment: @Bartosz - Expressing $P$ as a relation??  No, we're trying to express $P$ as an ESO Horn formula -- and $M$ could be one of the second order relations in such a formula.. And we were trying to obtain an ESO Horn formula for $P$, with or without using a Turing machine.